# How to open popups through links with jquery mobile when there are ampersands(?) within the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, get

I'm developing a web app using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5. I have a page where I pass GET parameters, e.g. like this:

```
index.php?page=locations&id=12
```

However, when entering the site with this URL **and switching to another page using page transitions**, there is no way a popup can be opened like this:

```
<a href="#myPopup">click me</a>
```

Popups can still be opened using the `$("#myPopup").popup('open');` function call, but this is not what I want.

If I remove the `&id=12` from the URL, the above link works correctly, so the problem must be the "&" sign within the URL breaking something internal in JQM. I guess there's some hidden referrer which still points to the original URL containing the `&id=12`.

This can be tested using the following: I've switched to page

```
index.php?page=users
```

coming originally from

```
index.php?page=locations&id=12
```

Then I changed the URL to the following by hand:

```
index.php?page=users#myPopup
```

What I got then was:

```
index.php?page=locations&id=12#myPopup
```

(which did nothing).

So is there any way I can get rid of this problem without having to switch to using Javascript calls? I also need the GET parameters within my PHP scripts, so switching to another method is not what I'd like to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally, the popups are used to display a bit of information from that same page. Can you expand upon what youy're trying to accomplish or how you get to index.php?page=locations&id=12#myPopup

Comment: Thank you! Well, since I switch pages using page transitions, I dynamically load popups into the DOM. However, the effect I described affects any popup, so I could even have an empty popup in the DOM and it wouldn't open as well. What I exactly want to do is switching from one page which contains any parameters separated by ampersands in the URL to another one which doesn't and open a popup there.